# Download ieee1394 for ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, kernel, downloads

I'm search in internet where I can download the driver ieee1394 for a kernel version 5.0.0-32-generic, but I can't find it.

Could somebody give me the url to download it?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need a driver. Firewore support is in Linux kernel for a long time.

Comment: That's right, thank you.

Comment: Could you see this other post, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205159/adapt-old-driver-to-a-new-version-of-it-ubuntu-18-lts? I have other problems. Thank you so much.